# Downward Role Variable Propagation?

Tags: ansible

I'm currently reading [the Ansible Variables guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html) as I'm working [on a role](https://github.com/naftulikay/ansible-role-vim). My role optionally depends on a number of roles based on certain variables:

```
---
galaxy: { ...}
dependencies:
  - role: naftulikay.rust-dev
    when: include_rust_dev
```

The [`rust-dev`](https://github.com/naftulikay/ansible-role-rust-dev) role uses a `rust_user` variable to specify which user to install Rust for.

The main role takes a `vim_user` variable to specify which user to configure Vim for. I'd like to bind `rust_user` to the value of `vim_user` so that if `include_rust_dev`, the `vim_user` is specified as the default for the underlying role's `rust_user`.

Where should I define `rust_user` in the Vim role which depends on the Rust role? If I put it in `vim-personal/defaults/main.yml`, will this propagate downward into the `rust-dev` role?

I'm going to try this out and post my findings, but does anyone know off-hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the answer is *yes*, default variables for a parent role pass down into child roles.

I defined `rust_user` in `vim-personal/defaults/main.yml` and this was propagated down into the `rust-dev` role without any other manual intervention.